# arrange your string in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, printing, pretty-print

```
for k, v in country_cap_dict.items():
    print "%s : %s" % (k,v)
```

my for loop is giving me output like this

```
           US : Washington
           Canada : Ottawa
           Germany: Berlin
           France : Paris
           England : London
           Switzerland : Bern
           Austria : Vienna
           Netherlands : Amsterdam
```

How can I improve readability so that output looks like:

```
           US :          Washington
           Canada :      Ottawa
           Germany:      Berlin
           France :      Paris
           England :     London
           Switzerland : Bern
           Austria :     Vienna
           Netherlands : Amsterdam
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C style string formatting in Python:

http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html

So, you can specify how much padding to give.

```
'%-24s %s' % ("US", "Washington")
'%-24s %s' % ("Brazil", "Washington") //padded to 24 spaces width between
```

Result:

```
'US                       Washington'
'Brazil                   Washington'
```

Comment: It just shifts all values by the distance of 24 spaces. I don't want that. I want all the values of the dictionary to be properly alligned. Say in one vertical column like I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Add '\t' after the first %s like so:

```
print "%s : \t%s" % (k,v)
```

Comment: Use the formatting operator with field widths, it's much more flexible.